# Command executed through Proc::Async is not "tapped" correctly

Tags: linux, raku

I have a good like this... straight from the documentation

```
my $proc = Proc::Async.new: ‘raku’, ‘script.raku’;
$proc.stdout.tap(-> $v { print "Output: $v" }, quit => { say 'caught exception ' ~ .^name });
$proc.stderr.tap(-> $v { print "Error:  $v" });
my $promise = $proc.start;
Thread.start: {  await $promise;}
sleep 30;
```

The script produces data on stdout and stderr.
But
it only prints one line ..
Output:something

It stops printing information out... The script produces much more output..
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3):

You need an `await $promise` at the end of your program, otherwise it might just exit before the program you call has finished running.

**Update** (after OP edited his post).

OP also said off stackoverflow:

> The full output is printed when the program ends.. with a considerable delay.

If that's the case, the problem is likely with the program that is called, that it buffers its STDOUT (and possible STDERR), and so the observing program doesn't even have early access to its output.

Calling [flush](https://docs.raku.org/routine/flush) on the appropriate handle in the called program might help.

Comment: no , I added more information.

Comment: If I run the same program in command line, this does not happen... Lines are printed out earlier.

Comment: running a program in the terminal directly usually enables line buffering, running it in a pipe switches it to block buffering. I guess you'll get the same result if you run your other program through `| cat`.